# Instead of Inbuilt Keyclock embedded db, can I use external db for storing user?

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services

I want to use Keyclock for springboot services. But Instead if storing users data in keyclock embedded db, I want to have communication between Keyclock and external sql-server db.

Is it possible that keyclock can talk to external db? If yes then How. I did not find any document related to that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement an adapter for your specific DB. Keycloak's service provider interface (SPI) is called the *UserStorage SPI*.
It is well documented in the [Keycloak Server Developer Guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi).
You can also find an example implementation for that SPI in the [examples zip](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/archive/latest.zip)